# How do you remove options from the Rich Text Editor?

Tags: 2013, rich-text, rte

I want to trim the options down to just a few basic options like bold, underline, and italic . How do I remove unwanted buttons from the Rich Text Editor (font button, color button etc)?

I'm thinking I can do this somehow with JavaScript and CSS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With SharePoint Designer, in the option of the column you can disable "Rich Text".
Or, in the list configuration, you can access de column options.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented the same thing a couple of days ago. The way I've done this was:

1. Create a control (don't forget to add a safe control entry for it):

   `<Control
      ControlAssembly="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
      ControlClass="Project.CustomActions.Control1"
      Sequence="1000"
      Id="AdditionalPageHead">
   </Control>`

I needed this in the page edit mode. Your requirements might be different. If it's a new form, consider adding a custom action instead of a control:

`<CustomAction 
       Id="Project.CustomActions.CustomAction1Id"
       Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
       Sequence="1"
       ControlAssembly="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
       ControlClass="Project.CustomActions.CustomAction">
    </CustomAction>`

2. Handle OnLoad event in the control class. The class needs to implement a `WebControl` class:

   ```
      protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
      {
       this.EnsureChildControls();
       base.OnLoad(e);
       this.Visible = false;

       if (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.Edit)
       {
           SPRibbon ribbon = SPRibbon.GetCurrent(this.Page);
           HideCustomActions(ribbon);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Hide custom actions:

   `ribbon.TrimById(buttonToTrim);`

You can get the IDs of the Ribbon buttons using IE developer tool (F12):
[image]

P.S - Stackexchange's code formating options are ridicullous.